# Source script in bash with $ character present in the script

Tags: bash, shell, tomcat

When tomcat starts up, it checks for $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh and if it exists, it sources this file as shown below

```
. $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh
```

Following are the contents of my setenv.sh file

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Daccesskey=abc$def"
```

When it is sourced, the value "**-Daccesskey=abc$def**" is being read as "**-Daccesskey=abcdef**". Character **$** is gone.

I am generating the setenv.sh file. How should i specify the contents of setenv.sh such that i read the value "**abc$def**"?

Comment: `When it is sourced....it shouldn't be read as "-Daccesskey=abcdef"` by the default behaviour.. See the comments of [\[ this \]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38387938/1620779) answer

Answer (score 3):

First of all i guess value would have read as `-Daccesskey=abc` and not `-Daccesskey=abcdef` because `$def` would be expanded to empty value.

If you want to override, you can escape the dollar sign by using `\`:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Daccesskey=abc\$def"
```

Comment: `would have read as -Daccesskey=abc` is not correct as per the question.

Comment: How would bash remove $ sign alone? Doesn't it try to expand `$def`?

Comment: I did test and it expanded `$def` to empty value

Comment: I stand corrected :) I thought, it would try to expand `$d`,`$de` and `$def` and when the variables are not set it  would simple ignore the `$` That is not the case.  In fact that is the reason to use `${}`

Answer (score 0):

For a literal `$` just escape it ;)

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Daccesskey=abc\$def"
```